# Apache 2.4 restrict URL to certain IPs

Tags: ip, apache-2.4, 301-redirect, restriction

I am trying to restrict a specific URL to be available outside the network only to specific IP addresses.
When a user outside tries to access that URL and not from the list of IPs he should be redirected to the homepage.

This is what I've tried so far without any luck.
The last part it redirects everyone to the homepage regardless of IP.

```
<Location "/secret">
#    <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != -ipmatch '123.123.123.123/255.255.255.255'">
#    Redirect 303 "/secret" /
#    </If>

RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!123\.123\.123\.123"
RewriteRule .* / [R,L]

LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
</Location>
```

PS: the /secret URL is in fact a virtual URL and does not exist physically on the drive.

Comment: the If statements are commented out ? Enable rewriting - `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: The <If> statement is one version that I tried. The RewriteEngine On directive is declared earlier. That's the reason it redirects everyone

Comment: I think you should un-mark the selected answer, because it is not valid for Apache 2.4 as you requested (it gives wrong information to people passing by)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Require [ip|host|env]` to specify who has access to your vhost or location.

```
    <Directory "/docroot">
        Require ip 10.10.11.12
    </Directory>
```

When it comes to redirecting, think about a [custom error page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html). This is much more general, because every unauthorized access should provoke a 403 error and thus can be evaluated easily.

I never did this with apache, but use this strategie with nginx. For apache something like this should do:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://homepage.example.com
```

> Custom error documents are configured using the ErrorDocument directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory context. It may be used in .htaccess files if AllowOverride is set to FileInfo. (from the apache docs)

Comment: This looks like a set of  Apache httpd 2.2 configuration. Will it still work with 2.4 ?

Comment: At least the `ErrorDocument` part is from the 2.4 docs. I don't use apache, since nginx is around, but assumed that `Order`,`Deny` and `Allow` are still around in apache 2.4

Comment: Thanks, but I doesn't help. I forgot to mention, but I updated the question, the /secret URL is in fact a virtual URL and does not exist physically on the drive. The URL it self is a rewrite from index.php that's why I used the <Location> directive.

Comment: It seems to be working with the ErrorDocument directive only if I provide the full URL including domain and protocol. I will research further. Thanks.

Comment: This syntax is deprecated in apache 2.4

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This is for Apache 2.2 not 2.4 as the question implies... This will not work.

Answer (score 27):

The Order, Deny, and Allow options have been replaced in Apache 2.4 with

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/public>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You can explicitly restrict addresses through the use of the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/public>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 192.168.0.1
</Directory>
```

The exact opposite is true as well, to restrict all and only allow a sub-set use the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/public>
    Require host example.com
    Require ip 192.168.0.1
</Directory>
```

More information is available on the [Apache 2.4 access control documentation.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

In regards to your question (edited my own due to a lack of points to add a comment,) you should be able to simply set an ErrorDocument with the index set as the URL-path:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/public>
    Require host example.com
    Require ip 192.168.0.1
    ErrorDocument 401 /index.html
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Linztm! But this solves only partially my problem. I don't want to only block the user but also redirect him to the homepage.

Comment: It seems to be working with the ErrorDocument directive only if I provide the full URL including domain and protocol. I will research further. Thanks.

Comment: I found at least one case when you need to use `allow` though deprecated, `Require 127.0.0.1`  still allow access by external address from local machine, where as allow syntax allow only from 127 address.

Answer (score 3):

For Apache 2.4, you can use <RequireAny>.
You can do it in a vhost or an .htaccess file....

```
SetEnvIF IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx AllowThisIP  # Or X-Real-IP
SetEnvIF IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy AllowThisIP
<RequireAny>
  Require env AllowThisIP
  Require host example.com
</RequireAny>
```

Apache docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany